# Html styled list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I just have been looked into Google's source code and I saw that the side bar is created from the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags which the use for them is making list.

So as I said I saw their side menu bar and I tried to do the same, something like this : http://jsbin.com/oyibok/edit#javascript,html,live

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li> dsds </li>
    <li> dsds </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

not quiet worked out, is there any technique that I can use to do the same as Google's did and make a list without the followed dot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get rid of the dots, just add the following css:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Very simple answer, but perfect none the less :)

Answer (score 1):

yes - the answer is css. you should do something like

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none; /* look mom - no dots */
}

ul li {
  display:inline; /* look mom - no block display - only if you want a horizontal nav */
}

a {
  text-decoration:none /* look mom - no underline */
}
```

also as you may notice if this is a navbar you probably would put links inside the `li` element with `a` elements
by the way - all modern nav bars are lists..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing the bullets/dots in CSS, you may also want to reset the margins to `margin: 0px` if you want the top-level list items to be flush with the left side of their container.

In most browsers, just removing the bullets still leaves white space where they normally are.

Answer (score 0):

A list has the bullet points by default, and also some margins and padding.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">list item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

With CSS you can change the way the list looks.

```
<style>
    /* the styles go in between the style tag */
</style>
```

You can use CSS to grab each element in the list and change the properties.

For example I usually start by removing the list style, margin and padding.

```
ul { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Next you can change the link or anchor tags to have a width and height and background colour.

Links by defaul are inline elements, which means they don't force a new line but flow inline.. I need them to be displayed as a block element so I can style it.

```
ul a:link,
ul a:visited { display:block; width:100px; height:20px; line-height:20px; background:blue;    }
```

Now when the user hovers the mouse over the link you can change its colour again, CSS stacks so all the styles you wrote above will still apply but we can over write whatever we choose.

```
ul a:hover { background:orange; }
```

Some reading: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp

Once you know how to select elements using CSS, you will be able to create pretty much anything.

You can give HTML elements a unique id or a class.
An id is used to select a single element, on it's own.

But if you have a lot of elements, a class is used.

"#" for Ids and a "." For classes.

Example:

```
<div id="something">some text wrapped in a div with an id</div>

<div class="something">a div with a class</div>
<div class="something">a div with a class</div>
<div class="something">a div with a class</div>

<style>
#something { background:red; }
.something { background:blue; }
</style>
```

The startings
http://jsbin.com/oyibok/5/edit